# How to get Deployment Risk (Bluemix Devops Insights) Gate pass?

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, devops-insights

I setup **bluemix devops pipeline** with DevOps insights Gate node included. Unit test result (mocha format) and coverage result (istanbul format) have been uploaded in test jobs (using **grunt-idra3 npm plugin** as same as the tutorial did ⇒[github url](https://github.com/open-toolchain/DemoDRA)).

However, my gate job is still failed, though unit test is showing 100% pass.

Much appreciated if someone can help me.

**Snapshot of DevOps Insight⇒**
[image: Snapshot of DevOps Insight]

**All unit test passed, but still "decision for Unit Test" is red failed**⇒
[image]

**Detail of policy & rules :**
policy "Standard Mocha Test Policy"

Rule-1: Functional verification test,
Rule type: Functional verification test,
Results file format: xUnit,
Percent Passes: 100%

Rule-2: Istanbul Coverage Rule,
Rule type: Code Coverage,
Result file format: istanbul,
Minimum code coverage required: 80%

Rule-3: Mocha Unit Test Rule,
Rule type: Unit Test,
Results file format: xUnit,
Percent Passes: 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending almost 3 weeks on this, finally I get DevOps Gate Job all green. Thanks @Vijay Aggarwal, and everyone else who helped on this issue.

Here is actually what happened and how it is solved finally.

---

**[Root Cause]**

1. DevOps Insight is "environment sensitive" in decision phase (not in
   result display though). In my case, I put "STAGING" into "Environment Name" property of Gate Job, thus DevOps Insight does not properly evaluate all the test result I uploaded in both Staging phase and Build phase.
2. DevOps Rules are
   "Result Format Sensitive" too, so people must be careful in choosing
   "reporter" for Mocha or Istanbul. In my case, I defined the gulp
   file as follows, but incorrectly set result type to "mocha" in
   Policy Rule definition.

   ```
    gulp.task("test", ["pre-test"], function() {
    return gulp.src(["./test/**/*.js"], {read: false})
      .pipe(mocha({
      reporter: "mocha-junit-reporter",
      reporterOptions: {
      mochaFile: './testResult/testResult-summary.xml'
      }
    }));
   ```

---

**[How it is solved]**

1. Keep "Environment Name" field empty for Gate Job.
2. In Rule definition page (inside DevOps Policy page), make sure the format type of unit test result is "xUnit".

[Screenshot when DevOps Gate is finally passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M8z0.png)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a mismatch between the format specified in Rule (xUnit) and the format of the actual test results (Mocha).

Please update the rule to select "Mocha" format for Unit Tests.  Then rerun the gate.

Comment: I tried to select "Mocha" for unit tests and rerun the gate, but nothing changed. It is still failed.

Comment: Hi Mao.  We will investigate Friday morning. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Vijay, thanks very much. Looking forward to more hints from your side.

Comment: Hi Mao.  In the job where you run the Gate, it seems you are specifying an Environment name.  Please leave that field empty and run the gate again.

Comment: Thanks @Vijay, I have finally solved this issue based on your advice. See the comment below for details.